# Run/Debug ElasticSearch in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, elasticsearch

Is there a way to debug *ElasticSearch server* in realtime from *IntelliJ*? I don't have any exp with *Maven*. My goal is to have it running while I can debug it and inspect variables and the execution flow.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37922520/how-can-i-setup-and-run-debug-elasticsearch-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok found it. Use the Run menu of IntelliJ to add a new run configuration.

- Run
- Edit configurations
- +
- Set `Main class` to **org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap**
- Set `VM options` to **-Des.foreground=yes**

Voila. [Credits](http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/running-binary-of-elasticsearch-source-code-after-building-td3877658.html).

Comment: Or just start the `ElasticsearchF` class, even simpler.

Comment: What is the updated answer for 2.x?  `ElasticsearchF` no longer seems to exist, and `Bootstrap` has no main method.

Answer (score 3):

You have not indicated if you are asking to debug / step-into the Elastic Search (ES) client or sever code.

**For Client Code**

As long as the sources are attached, yes you can debug it. If you are using Maven, you can ask it to download (and attach) the sources assuming they are available in the [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/). (Elastic Search does deploy its sources to maven central, so you should be good there. If not, you would have to "manually" attach the source jar in the Project Structure dialog.)

To get maven to download and attach, open the maven tool window and click the "Download..." button [image] and select either *Download Sources* or *Download Sources and Documentation*. IDEA will now download and attach all the available source (and/or javadoc) JARs for all the dependencies/libraries in your project. If desired, you can configure maven to always do this. To set it for the current project, click the settings button [image] in the maven tool window ans select the *Importing* node, or go to *Settings > [Project Settings] > Maven > Importing*. In the dialog, check the "Automatically Download" Sources and/or Documentation options. To set this as the default for all future projects you create, go to *File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Maven > Importing* and make the setting.

Once the sources are attached, you will be able to step into the elastic search code, or open one a class by either 1) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to search for and enter a class, typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> a second time to include library classes in your search or 2) using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (when your cursor is on a method call) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+`Click` to go to the method declaration. You can then set breakpoints.

**For Server Code**

You will need to create an elastic search project with the source code. The easiest thing would be to clone their repo (or otherwise check it out). You could also just attach the ES server libraries (including sources) to your project.

If you are running elastic search locally, just create a local Run/Debug configuration to run ES and launch via *Debug*. If running ES on a remote server, you will need to create a remote debug configuration and then attach to the remote ES server (which will need to be started with the proper Java Debug properties.) See *Help > IntelliJ IDEA > Reference > Dialog > Run/Debug Configurations > Run/Debug Configuration: Remote* and *Help > IntelliJ IDEA > Language and Framework-Specific Guidelines > Java EE > Working with Application Servers > Working with Server Run/Debug Configurations* for more information.

Comment: Hi, I am asking about elasticsearch server. I have imported the project to intellij and i also packaged it using maven target. My question is how to create a target that will run elastic search.

Comment: Since they have moved to gradle now. Is there any way to debug elastic search code in Intellij?