# How can I setup and run/debug ElasticSearch in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, intellij-idea, gradle

I am trying to learn how ES works however I haven't been able to run it from an IDE. I want to run the 2.3.3 build which still uses Maven as its build system but keep getting errors. Can someone tell me how I can do this in IDEA after I download the repository in detail ie. the configuration etc.

I downloaded the repository from github, then I imported the project into intellij
and used the following configurations:

Main class: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch

Vm options:

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1g
-Xss256k
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=logs/heapdump.hprof
-Delasticsearch
-Des.foreground=yes
-Djava.library.path=lib/sigar
-ea
-Des.config=C:\elasticsearch-2.3.3\core\src\test\resources\config\elasticsearch.yaml>/elasticsearch.yml
-Des.logger.level=DEBUG
-Des.path.home=C:\elasticsearch-2.3.3
```

working directory: ES directory

environment variable: ES_TEST_LOCAL=true

use classpath of module: elasticsearch(1)(org.elasticsearch)

and then I get the following errors when i try to run:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fHMB.png)

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/2.3/CONTRIBUTING.md#contributing-to-the-elasticsearch-codebase

Comment: What errors?  Building and running are two different things.

Comment: I tried using eclipse but when I use-> mvn eclipse:eclipse, I keep getting the following error:  Failed to execute goal on project distributions: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.elasticsearch.distribution:distributions:pom:2.3.3-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:tests:2.3.3-SNAPSHOT, org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:2.3.3-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:jar:tests:2.3.3-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ was cached in the local repository,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pre-requisites:

1. Build the root project : mvn clean package -DskipTests (or execute run.sh)
2. copy ./distribution/src/main/resources/config to ./core/.

Create a Run/Debug configuration as follows:

```
Main Class: org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch   
VM Options: -Des.path.home=/code/elasticsearch/core   
Program Arguments: start   
Classpath of Module : [select the core project]
```

Comment: Note the 5.x line doesn't use maven, it uses gradle

Answer (score 8):

For 5.x - From command line:

```
> gradle run --debug-jvm
Running elasticsearch in debug mode, suspending until connected on port 8000
[elasticsearch] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

From Intellij, create a Remote debug configuration and set the port to 8000.
[image]

Comment: That's it?  Are you then running a node after that?

Comment: @Jonathan, yeah, that's it. A node will be running.

Comment: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':client:rest'.
> java.lang.AbstractMethodError (no error message)

I change the command from `gradle run --debug-jvm` to `./gradlew run --debug-jvm` fixed